# symfony route annotation requirements constraints

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

Here is the simple symfony Route:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{param}", requirements={"param": "(one|two)"})
 */
```

But how can I set dynamic requirements from the array or entity feature like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{param}", requirements={"param": "array or entity"})
 */
```

p.s. the problem appears about the same Routes like /products/{vendors} and /products/{models}. I want to catch valid route by the requirements of the route.

thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `requirements` as they are just regular expressions, so they cannot detect things like the type of the parameter. In fact I believe there is no way to achieve what you want to do: how would you "send" an entity or an array in a URL? If you are using parameter converters, then the `requirements` should refer to the original, not converted, URL

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to do. Could you provide some detailed examples in your question

Comment: Sorry, was busy... There is a number of my routes for one category of many:                                       /category/{weight}, /category/{height}, /category/{weight}/{height}, /category/{weight}/{height}/{other,                  I used the following before:                                      /category/weight-23/height-54/other-alphabetical and matched needle by regex using keyword of parameter (e.g. weight), now I want to get rather beautiful and valid routes like: /category/32 (catching weight not height), /category/54 (catching height not weight)....

Comment: How do you pretend to differentiate  /category/32 from /category/54 and decide that the first is weight while the second is height? This would be magic!

Comment: Yes, it's looks like, but I wanted to differentiate that by nonException or notNullResult of the selection from database (entity) or array, i.e. route matched when nonException or notNullResult event called.

Comment: You cannot do that using just routing. Use a single controller and in the controller test if you get any result for your id for weight, height, etc... and proceed as needed

Answer (score 0):

This annotation format will work for your purpose:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test/{param}", requirements={"param" = "one|two"})
 */
```